# Can node-fibers be implemented using ES6 generators?

Tags: node.js, generator, coroutine, ecmascript-harmony, node-fibers

Wikipedia suggests that [coroutines can be implemented with generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#Comparison_with_generators).  Does this mean [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) could be implemented using [ES6 generators](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators)?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like https://github.com/visionmedia/co ?

From the README:

```
var co = require('co');

co(function *(){
  var a = yield get('http://google.com');
  var b = yield get('http://yahoo.com');
  var c = yield get('http://cloudup.com');
  console.log(a.status);
  console.log(b.status);
  console.log(c.status);
})()

co(function *(){
  var a = get('http://google.com');
  var b = get('http://yahoo.com');
  var c = get('http://cloudup.com');
  var res = yield [a, b, c];
  console.log(res);
})()
```

There is a new web framework called koa (http://koajs.com) that's based on this.

Comment: Good stuff.  Thanks for the heads up.  I was wondering if it's possible to build something that's syntax compatible with [fibrous](https://github.com/goodeggs/fibrous) on top of generators.  I believe it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I've coded a wrapper around Fibers called wait.for: https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Then I've coded *the same functionality* with generators: https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor-ES6

You can compare both to see how Generators can replace node-Fibers, but with different syntax.

One important difference, which makes impossible to have the same API, 
is that ES6's generators bodies are implemented with a special syntax: `function*`
while node-fibers allows you use any js function.

Answer (score 0):

I [tried to port a very small subset](http://bites.goodeggs.com/posts/fibrous-on-harmony-generators/) and failed.  The crux was that node-fibers's `Fiber.yield()` halts execution all the way up the Fiber's call stack, while a generator's `yield` only halts the immediate function.  While you may be able to implement a system that behaves similarly (like [Task.js](http://taskjs.org/)), it seems an API compatible implementation is impossible.

Comment: Did you try to use `yield*`? It allows you to nest generator functions so that you can also yield in the nested generator function.

Comment: broken link! please fix.

Comment: @nalply, fixed.  Thanks!